# Using OnPause and OnResume in an application

Tags: android

I am making an application in which i want to let the control go to some activity and then to come back. When I have searched about that problem, I came to know that this problem could be solved by using `OnPause()` and `OnResume()`, but I don't know how to use them.

This is the code where I am transferring the control to some other activity. Please tell me how to use `OnPause()` and `OnResume()` in this regard.Thanks in advance.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MCQ.this,ConfigActivity.class);
            int ClassIndex = 2;
            intent.putExtra("ClassIndex", ClassIndex);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not making too much sense. When you call `startActivity()`, Android will put your current `Activity` to the background, and start (or bring to foreground) the new `Activity` specified in your `Intent`.

`onPause()` called when your `Activity` disappears from the screen, eg. the system either puts it in the background, or terminates it.

`onResume()` is called when your `Activity` becomes visible on the screen, eg. either after `onCreate()` if Android created a new instance of your `Activity`, or when the system brings your `Activity` back from the background.

There is no explicit passing of control between `Activities`. If it is on the top of the activity stack (visible on the device screen), than you can interact with it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 1):

`onPause()` and `onResume()` are called by android.
Your job is to implement these methods. onPause and onStop are called at your launching activity by Android, and onCreate, onStart and onResume at the Activity your starting. If you want to go back, you usually just press the back button at your device.
You might want to take a look at [the Android devGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) and especially at the Activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confused as to what `onPause()` and `onResume()` are used for.

`onResume()` is called when the Activity is about to show it's view to the user.  You can use your intent in this method so the main Activity would instantly go to the `ClassIndex` activity.  However, when you leave the `ClassIndex` activity, `onResume()` will be called again which will send you back to `ClassIndex`.

`onPause()` is called when the Activity is leaving.  Whether this is for locking the screen or moving to another `Activity`.  In this case, when you call `startActivity` in the main Activity, Android will call `onPause()` in the main activity before entering the new one.

What you may want in this case is to use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and use it to determine if you're coming back from your `ClassIndex` activity or not.  If not, then start it. If so, then move on to the main activity.

A better solution may-or-may-not be to start the app in `ClassIndex` and move to your main activity when the user is done with it.  This would be the case if you want to move to `ClassIndex` every time the user enters the app.